# create missing directories in path

Tags: python

Is there a clean way of taking a path like this:

```
/foo/bar/faz/baz/
```

where `foo` and `bar` exist, but `faz` and `baz` don't, and create create `faz` and `baz` while leaving `foo` and `bar` alone? (Of course, this should work for something like `exists/exists/exists/doesnt_exist/doesnt_exit/doesnt_exist/doesnt_exist` or whatever (number of non existants/existants is variable) too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) does exactly that.